# sudoedit: why use it over sudo vi?

Tags: linux, sudo

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudoedit):

```
sudoedit /etc/file
```

creates a copy of the file, opens it as the current user, and when saved overwrites the existing file with the copy.

whereas

```
sudo vi /etc/file
```

opens the file as root

The man page states that sudoedit is different from sudo because:

> the editor is run with the invoking user's environment unmodified

Is the first method safer, if so why? Are there other reasons for using sudoedit instead of sudo vi?

Comment: It has some drawbacks. For example, [sometimes syntax highlight is lost](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6784/how-can-i-automate-filetype-detection-when-using-sudoedit).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question while searching for something completely unrelated, but I thought I would add the following important distinction, which has not been mentioned at all so far: **sudoedit doesn't run your editor as root.**

```
$ sudo vim /etc/farts.conf
```

Will simply run vim as root, allowing it to read the file. The downside is that the editor now also runs as root and can do anything. If you just wanted to allow a user to edit a config file and nothing else, too bad, you just gave them **root** on the whole system. Nothing prevents me from spawning a shell from vim with `:sh` or `:!command`, and since they're sub processes, they will also run as root.

On the other hand:

```
$ sudoedit /etc/farts.conf
```

will actually operate differently. It will create a copy with a unique name in /tmp with permissions locked down to only your user, and then spawn your editor normally, without root privileges, on that copy.

Once you exit your editor, it will compare the temporary file and original file, and safely replace the original with your edit if it changed.

In this scenario, it becomes possible to allow a user to edit a system file, but not allow them to run random binaries as root or poke everywhere on the file system.

That is mainly the actual distinction, the rest that has been mentioned is just neat side effects.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, `sudo vim` already explicitly mentions your default editor, which is not necessary if you have it defined in `$EDITOR`. `sudoedit` spares you from defining the editor every time you want to edit something—and on a multiuser system it allows everyone to use the editor they personally like.

How so? Consider a system where normal users only get `sudo` privileges for editing certain files. They are restricted from running `sudo` with anything else though. You would have to allow them to `sudo vi` and `sudo vim` and `sudo nano` and `sudo emacs` and `sudo pico` (et cetera). Instead of having to do that, you could simply allow them to `sudoedit` the file, with their choice of setting `$EDITOR` to whatever they like. (Imagine you'd force an Emacs lover to use Vim…)

Another issue is that if your `$EDITOR` is set to `vim`, and you have customization settings for it in your user's `.vimrc`, those settings will not be used if you use `sudo vim` or `sudo $EDITOR`. `sudoedit` however preserves the calling user's environment, and therefore your settings.

See also: [What's so great about sudoedit?](http://www.wingtiplabs.com/blog/posts/2013/03/13/sudoedit/)

Comment: Also the user should be using `visudo` instead of `sudoedit`.

Comment: @EvanDarwin No, that is unrelated. `visudo` is only used to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file in a safe manner (to prevent you from locking yourself out). `sudoedit` is a command to edit *any* file.

Comment: I'm aware, for some reason my brain saw a "/etc/sudoers" in his question somewhere. Maybe I need some more coffee.

Comment: -1 because this answer totally misses the point of sudoedit. The main reason for the existence of sudoedit are security reasons, as described in the answer of @mr_daemon.

Comment: @vog You're right. The other answer came way later. I wasn't aware if it.