# How do I change the language of the Linux subsystem in Windows 10 (WSL)?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

After installing Bash in Windows 10 I noted that it is using Swedish in the linux applications. My Windows 10 installation is in English.

I have tried to reinstall bash after changing the default input language to english using

```
lxrun /uninstall /full

lxrun /install
```

But it is still using swedish texts in the linux apps, e.g. in nano.

So how can I force the Linux subsystem to install with english language?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installation should automatically set the Ubuntu locale to match the locale of your Windows install.  You can change the Ubuntu locale manually using the shell.

1. Run this command in bash.exe to change the language to US English:

   ```
   sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF8
   ```

   If you get a `sudo: unable to resolve host` error whenever you run `sudo`,

   - Verify that you have a hostname set (with the `hostname` command).

     - If it isn't set, add it to the `/etc/hostname` file.
     - Ensure that `/etc/hostname` contains *only* the hostname.

     Edit the file with `sudoedit /etc/hostname`
     (assuming you can get that to work); see [this](https://superuser.com/q/785187/150988).
   - Ensure that your `/etc/hosts` file contains entries
     for your actual hostname (spelled *exactly* the same) and/or `localhost`. 
     Again, use `sudoedit`.

   See [Error message when I run sudo: unable to resolve host](https://askubuntu.com/q/59458/309110)
   for more information.
2. Relaunch the `bash.exe` for the changes to take effect.
3. If that doesn't fix it, try restarting the service:

   ```
   sc stop  lxssmanager
   sc start lxssmanager
   ```

If you want to learn more about the bash in WSL,
you can [read the FAQ by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq).

Comment: Seems that a restart of the service is also required for the change to take effect: "sc stop lxssmanager" , "sc start lxssmanager". I got an error when running the update-locale cmd: "sudo: unable to resolve host ...".

Comment: *"WSL install will automatically detects the Ubuntu locale to match the locale of your Windows install"* I'd rather say "misdetects." I got Finnish, I have all settings on English, except keyboard layout and date format. That's not really a Finnish locale in my book.

Comment: I got the error `sudo: unable to resolve host` while trying to run that command. It worked when I ran it without `sudo`.

Comment: @sgtfrankieboy It won't persist without `sudo`. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none) and its answers.

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8, missing the '-'

Comment: The `unable to resolve host` is there, but still this command works.

Comment: I have tried `LANG=fa.UTF8` for persian language, but getting this error: `*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings: LANG=fa.UTF8`

Answer (score 4):

[This manual](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Change-Locale-Language-and-Character-Set-in-Linux) describes different ways. Since in this case we are using Ubuntu, choose corresponding options. Summary:

- Change locale for current session only: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
- Change locale permanently for current user: add `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to `~/.bashrc`
- Change default system locale: use `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in
  `/etc/default/locale`

According to `locale -a` the following English locales are available in my system by default: `C`, `C.UTF-8`, `en_US.utf8`.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't the language already installed you need to use:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-en-base manpages
```

changing "en" to your locale, and then use the command to switch locale.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reinstalling bash, add the following line to the file `~/.bashrc`

```
LANG=c
```

Then you get english language bash.

Answer (score 1):

Non of these worked for me. Running Ubuntu18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver) on WSL Build 16299.

The workaround for me was from [Lri's solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93906/cal-command-start-monday):

```bsh
$ sudo apt install gcal
$ alias cal='gcal --starting-day=1'
```