# Linux Ubuntu Speakers Popping every few seconds

Tags: linux, audio, speakers, ubuntu-18.04

I'm new to Linux Ubuntu, long time Windows User, and glad I'm making the switch.  When setting up my desktop PC, I am subjected to an annoying and repetitive speaker 'pop' about every 2 seconds.  This pop occurs regardless of volume level.  It does stop if I unplug the audio jack to my speakers, and just use the speaker built into the motherboard.  If I play a sound, the popping stops while the sound is playing and for about 5 seconds after, then resumes.

I am running Linux Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.  The system information reports two Audio Adapters,
HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB & HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia

I did eventually find the solution to this problem, but I don't have enough reputation points to post Q&A together.

Answer (score 33):

The operation system's default behavior is to save power by turning off the Audio Adapter after 10 seconds.  This power-save feature is causing the popping, and can be disabled.

In Terminal type `sudo nano /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save` and change the value from 1 to 0.

Then type `sudo nano /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller` and change the value from Y to N.

On my system, this solved the audio popping problem immediately. However on reboot, the problem came back and I found these values had been reset.  To keep these values persistent, I had to add a line of code to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`  I added this after the last line of code in the file, `options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N`

Save the file, and you're good to go!

Much of my information came from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdmy8dMWitg

I had to piece together the "persistence after reboot" part, and my setting did reset even though I do not have TLP installed. Note that the video claims otherwise.

I was quite frustrated with Ubuntu until I figured this out.  I hope this helps many people solve their audio issues!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I also have this problem. I could fix the issue on my ubuntu. But when I turn off, restart or suspend the system, The problem is still occurred. What to do for shut down????

Comment: @Emad Helmi: Did you edit alsa-base.config?  You have to add a line of code at the end of this file, otherwise the speaker pop will come back when you restart the computer.  See my answer above.

Comment: @Glen: Yes! I edited that file. everything's ok when my ubuntu is on. just when I shut down my laptop, I again hear that sound. Also at the startup of the ubuntu, I hear that sound 2 or 3 times and after login, all thing's good! When I connect my  laptop to HDMI also, I hear that sound on shutdown or startup from both monitor and laptop speakers

Comment: not working.constant popping noise.

Answer (score 5):

As a followup to @Glen's answer, here is a script that performs the task:

```
fix_ubuntu_18_04_sound_pop_issue(){
    __heredoc__="""
    Script that fixes a popping sound due to a power saving feature

    References:
        https://superuser.com/questions/1493096/linux-ubuntu-speakers-popping-every-few-seconds
        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdmy8dMWitg
    """
    sudo echo "obtaining sudo"
    # First, there are two system files that need modification
    # Changing the values here should fix the issue in your current session. 
    cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
    cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
    # Flip the 1 to a 0
    sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save"
    # Flip the Y to a N
    sudo sh -c "echo N > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller"

    # To make this change persistant we must modify a config file
    if [ -f "/etc/default/tlp" ]; then
        # Some systems (usually laptops) have this controlled via TLP 
        sudo sed -i 's/SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1/SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0/' /etc/default/tlp
        # This line contained a typo, addressed on 2020-10-11 11:11 Bcn time
        sudo sed -i 's/SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y/SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=N/' /etc/default/tlp
    elif [ -f "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf" ]; then
        # Append this line to the end of the file
        text="options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N"
        fpath="/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf"
        # Apppend the text only if it doesn't exist
        found="$(grep -F "$text" "$fpath")"
        if [ "$found" == "" ]; then
            sudo sh -c "echo \"$text\" >> $fpath"
        fi
        cat "$fpath"
    else
        echo "Error!, unknown system audio configuration" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to Glen's answer, for reasons of security, it is better to use `sudoedit` in place of `sudo nano`. Note that you will also need to set the `EDITOR` environment variable.

So, instead of:

```
sudo nano /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

use

```
EDITOR=nano sudoedit /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

and instead of

```
sudo nano /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
```

use

```
EDITOR=nano sudoedit /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
```

The reason why `sudoedit` is better, is fully explained in this SuperUser question, [sudoedit: why use it over sudo vi?](https://superuser.com/q/785187/399707)