# sudo vim can't write file

Tags: vim, sudo

[image: terminal]

`spotify.desktop` can be written by root owner, so, I use `$ sudo vim spotify.desktop` to edit it, but, find that I can't save the modifications. The error is "only readable". Does anybody know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper way to do this is with the `sudoedit spotify.desktop` command, assuming you have the following in your .bashrc:

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR=$VISUAL
```

See [this accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/785187/sudoedit-why-use-it-over-sudo-vi) for the differences between `sudo vim` and `sudoedit`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write that file because it is on another filesystem that is read-only.

Check `mount | grep spotify`, you'll see that it's "ro" mounted. Even root cannot write this.

You'd need to edit the file(s) where they are mounted from and writeable on your disk.
In this case it is a snap archive, which you'd even need to unsquash first.

Are you sure the desktop file you are looking for is not rather in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` ?